# Sort Descriptor based on ordered to-many relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data

Description of my core data model:

- Project and Issues entities
- Project has an **ordered one-to-many relationship** to Issues named issues
- Issue has one-to-one relationship with Project named parentProject

Here is my code to obtain issues:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Issue")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "parentProject CONTAINS[cd] %@", argumentArray: [project])
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]

    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(
        fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
        managedObjectContext: dataManager.context,
        sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
        cacheName: nil)

    return arc
```

Even though I have all issues from the project object, I prefer to obtain issues using fetched results controller, so they will always be updated and I like the integration with tables. I also like that in navigation controller screen before the projects are displayed using FRC as well.

As you see in the code the Issues are sorted by the name parameter.

**However I'd like them to be sorted by the order I keep them in the NSMutableOrderedSet of project.**

AFAIK I cannot use NSSortDescriptor with comparator/selector when it's used to Core Data.

Do you know how to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you are not using :- NSSortDescriptor *sortStates = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"states"
                                                    ascending:NO
                                                   comparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {

Comment: @Vizllx as I mentioned in the questions, sort descriptor with comparator and selector doesn't work as a fetch request sort descriptor

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unsupported NSSortDescriptor (comparator blocks are not supported)'

Comment: can you please say by which parameter you kept "Issues" as OrderedSet in Project?

Comment: Is your intention to have issues from different projects intersperse in the list, or would you want them group together?

Comment: Shouldn't your return be `frc` instead of `arc` at the end?

Comment: I've come up against this issue in the past, and as far as I could determine, it's not possible to return the contents of `OrderedSet` in a FetchRequest in their "OrderedSet order". Not the answer you wanted, best I can suggest is to raise a bug with Apple.

Comment: I agree Ashley Mills,  I had to ditch the NSFRC.  Friggin apple.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the relationship keypath (in your case `parentProject`) it will sort according to the ordered set.  so you can use

```
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "parentProject.name", ascending: true),NSSortDescriptor(key: "parentProject", ascending: true)]
```

This will first sort them by project, then inside each project group it will be sorted by the same order as the ordered set in the relationship.  Optionally you can put each issue's project in a different section by using `sectionNameKeyPath`.

If you don't use `parentProject.name`  (or something like it - like `parentProject.lastUpdated`) first then they will ONLY be sorted according to the order of orderedSet.  In other words it will be all of the first issues, then all of the second issues etc.  This is probably not what you want.

Comment: How can you sort by `parentProject` which is ObjectID?

Comment: `parentProject` is a relationship. Core-data is smart enough to recognize that is a sorted relationship and sort it in the same way that is sorts the NSOrderedSet.

Comment: I was unable to do this.  Simply put, I do not think it is feasible to do NSFRC with orderedSet.  I removed my NSFRC and handled everything myself using my own methods

Comment: I made a test project with this code and it work.  I wonder what we are doing differently.

Answer (score 3):

You may not want to hear this, but unfortunately, you can't.  NSFetchedResultsController cannot be sorted using sortDescriptors based on the ordered one-to-many relationship.  You should file a bug with Apple. You should ditch your NSFetchedResultsController and handle it's delegate methods yourself.

Comment: What a shame.  I had a feeling it wasnt possible.  Filing a bug with Apple now.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a kluge, but anyway. It seems to me your first fetch is a filter.. e.g. show me issues for this project. Maybe you could perform a second fetch, on the selected issues, and this time not filtering them, but sorting them?

Regarding CoreData, I have a sorted fetch like this:

```
  func fetchItem() {
        print(#function)

        let sortDescriptor: NSSortDescriptor!
        let defaults: UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if defaults.integer(forKey: "sequenceSwitchValue") == 0 {
            sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "itemName", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(_:)))
        } else {
            sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "itemName", ascending: false, selector: #selector(NSString.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(_:)))
        }

        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: itemEntity)
        request.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        let predicate: NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "itemName == %@", incomingItemName)
        request.predicate = predicate


        do {
            items = try context.fetch(request) as! [ItemEntity]
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Error While Fetching Data From DB: \(error.userInfo)")
        }

        if items.count > 0 {
            let currentItem = items[0]
```

You may be able to work a relationship value into the predicate..

Answer (score -4):

The simplest way to keep order is to add a property for the "issue" entity. Something called `position` of type `Int`. And use sort Descriptor that would sort entities by this `position` property

Comment: Yes but do you plan on updating every since object when the position changes?

Comment: I don't have to update every single issue. Only those affected by the position change inside the project. It happens every time you insert item at index of an array. So i don't see a big problem here unless issues are  reordered very often in every project.

Comment: The project I am using is constantly reordering (drag and drop feature).  So this doesnt work.