# How to configure an NSFetchRequest to retrieve a to-many relationship

Tags: core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I've got a Core Data relationship set up like this:

```
Place               PlaceList
=====               =========
lists <<--------->> places
```

I'd like to populate an `NSFetchResultsController` with a given `PlaceList` instance's list of places. `places` is an ordered relationship, and `lists` is unordered. I'd like the fetch request to return the list of places in the order specified by the relationship.

I started out with this:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<Place>(entityName: "Place")
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "lists == %@", placeList)
request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "lists", ascending: true)]
```

When I fetch, though, no places come back. I've tried a bunch of ideas from other answers, trying all different predicates, and most result in exceptions thrown when the fetch request is executed.

I've tried, for example:

```
"ANY lists == %@"
"lists CONTAINS %@"
"%@ IN lists"
```

Comment: I would have expected “lists CONTAINS %@“ to work.  What result/error do you get in that specific case?

Comment: @pbasdf No error, but it returns an empty list.

Comment: If you `print(placeList.places!)`, what output do you get?

Comment: @pbasdf It prints the array of all three of the places I expect it to, with full Core Data descriptions. And when it prints each of the places' `lists` properties, they contain the single list I expect.

Comment: "ANY lists == %@", "lists CONTAINS %@" or "%@ IN lists" should work but you can't sort by `lists`.

Comment: @Willeke I tried sorting by another property, and you're right, it does work. But I was sorting by `lists`, because the `places` property is ordered, and I read that's how you get the list to sort in the order of the relationship. What do I sort by to get the results in the order I expect?

Comment: [Sort Descriptor based on ordered to-many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35222457/sort-descriptor-based-on-ordered-to-many-relationship)

Comment: @Willeke I had seen that, but was hoping maybe something changed in iOS 11.